# Is the $10K threshold for the 20% IRS "substantial understatement" penalty based on the aggregate or individual underpayments?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

The 20% penalty is assessed on the amount underpaid if such amount exceeds the greater of $10k or 10% of the taxes due. My underpayment was $12K in the aggregate. I had 3 gains (related to the same sale of a private company) that led to three underpayments that summed up to $12k. 2 of the 3 were well under the $10k threshold and amounted to 2-3% of taxes due. However, one transaction led to a $6k underpayment but pushed the aggregate total above the $10k threshold. Considering all three in total, the underpayment was 9.3% of taxes due. So it is the $10k threshold that makes it a "substantial understatement". However, if each of these three transactions is treated independently, only one would give rise to "substantial understatement", resulting in a much smaller FTP penalty. Is the penalty assessed in the aggregate (difference between total tax due and total tax paid on the return) or individually at the transaction for which mistakes were made? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The *substantial* **understatement** *penalty* applies if the tax that you show as *due* your Form 1040 Line 63 (Total tax due) differs from the *actual correct amount of tax due* by a substantial amount. This can occur for any number of reasons including inadvertently failing to compute some taxes due (e.g. AMT, Net Investment Tax) and so to include these amounts in the Total Tax due, but a major reason is that the taxpayer failed to report a large chunk of income on the tax return, and the IRS knows about this (e.g. you did not report money for which you received a Form 1099 or a W-2) or suspects this for some other reasons. This penalty differs from the penalty for failure to make sufficient *estimated tax* payments.  In one case, the IRS is suspecting that a fraudulent return has been filed, in the other, mere inattention to tax matters during the year.

As long as you report all your income, and don't have gross calculation errors while figuring the tax due, you do not owe an understatement penalty, only (possibly) an *underpayment* penalty that you can either allow the IRS to calculate for you and send you a bill for it, or compute for yourself on Form 2210. That you didn't pay sufficient income tax during the year (via withholding and/or estimated tax payments) is not a big deal; you pay the penalty and some interest, and that's all there is to it. On the other hand, if you underreported your income or claimed too many exemptions or claimed large numbers of charitable donations while making very few etc, and thereby ended up having a substantial *understatement* of the actual tax due is tax fraud and there is even a possibility of jail time in egregious cases.

Read more about the differences [here](https://www.irs.gov/uac/avoiding-penalties-and-the-tax-gap).

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. I reported on my '15 return all income shown on the 1099 but failed to use the installment method for this sale of private stock. The merger agreement held back 10% of the consideration in escrow which was distributed to me 1 year later. I held 3 securities in this company and overlooked surrendering one of the stock certificates until 2016 so this income did not show up on the 1099-B issued to me. I was not aware of the installment method at the time I filed in 2015 and had planned to recognize this gain on my 2016 return. IRS hasn't sent notice but I plan to fix.